# EAN Barcode image

Tags: magento-1.9, csv, barcode

if I have in my CSV the EAN value as number in a column called EAN and I'm importing it as a Magento attribute called EAN that at the moment I have set it to display on the frontend near to the SKU number, is there a way to show the EAN barcode image instead of the value number itself?

I'm using latest version of magento 1.9

Answer (score 0):

In your place if you already got attributes, I would use one of existing JS library. This is first record from google [lindell/JsBarcode](https://github.com/lindell/JsBarcode). and it look very good, here got usage example for ean-13 code.

```
JsBarcode("#ean-13", "1234567890128", {format: "ean13"});
```

Full demo you can see [here](https://codepen.io/lindell/pen/eZKBdO?editors=1010).

Comment: Thanks Mateusz, this is exactly what I want to achieve, regarding the value since I have multiple products there is a way to tell to get the attribute from magento? I found this code "echo $_attribute->getProductAttribute()->getAttributeCode();" but I really don't know how to include it in that JS code

Comment: Display product attribute value it's very easy
`$ean = $_product->getData('ean_13'));` or
 `$ean = $_product->getEan13());`

Comment: so I have to create an attribute called ean_13? and add that code you provided in javascript or directly in product page .phtml?

Comment: I created ean_13 you can do same or any other. And you have to include js lib  to magento and include it on js scripts. Then only style and execute on valid place. You have many options. Always you can order custom module for that.

Comment: Mateusz so I have to add in the <head> the JS library than add <?php $ean = $_product->getData('ean_13')); or $ean = $_product->getEan13()); ?> wherever I want to show the barcode? Because currently is what I'm doing but no  barcode is shown

Comment: You have to load product object first. Got public version to see?

Comment: still not i'm in dev